# Good "low level" graphics & image manipulating concepts tutorial for beginner

Tags: gimp, tutorial

I have programming background with some experience with image manipulation via GIMP and Fireworks. As working with image manipulators is part of my work sometimes I decided to improve my knowledge in this area.

However, when I try looking for something like

> GIMP tutorial

what I am able to find are only some tutorials with how to do this logo and that image, how to apply filter and so on.

What I would need is some decent tutorial explaining the basic graphics concepts like layers, channels and so on so I can see what is happening behind the tools used in GIMP.

What should I be looking for? What are possible resources to learn these thigns?

Comment: I understand your problem, but it is very difficult to teach the overall functionality of complex software without a case-study. One button, function or tool can be used in a multitude of ways, depending on what steps came before and what steps comes after. You will probably find images with arrows pointing to tools with a description, but this is not always very helpful... Personally, I think the best way is to create a fictional project, and then search specifically for a tutorial that would help you achieve that. And then of course increase complexity as you go along.

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of tutorials lynda.com is a great resource as you can choose a course aimed at your designated skill level.

Here is a good introduction course to GIMP:
http://www.lynda.com/course-tutorials/GIMP-Essential-Training/112673-2.html

Scan through the course subjects on the left to ensure it covers the elements you need.

Alternatively a free option is the online documentation: http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/
The list of topics here is quite comprehensive.